# Indiegogo commission on funds raised above goal

Tags: indiegogo

Indiegogo offers 2 pricing models:

1. Fixed funding:

   - 4% commission if you reach your goal;
   - 0% if you don't because all fund are return to donor.
2. Flexible funding:

   - 4% commission if you reach your goal;
   - 9% if you don't reach the goal, but you keep any donations.

My question is this: if a campaign gets donations way above the goal, is the commission always 4%? Why not set your campaign goal lower to reduce risk, and guarantee getting the lower commission rate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indiegogo have changed their policy.

> It's free to create a campaign! Here's all the information you need
>   about Indiegogo's fees and pricing.
>
> - Indiegogo's platform fee on all funds raised is 5%. It is free to sign up and create a campaign and fees are deducted from the funds you
>     actually raise (not the goal you set).
> - In addition, Stripe (credit card processor) charges a processing fee of 3% + 0.30 per transaction. There may also be an additional wire
>     transfer fee, depending on your currency and bank account location.
> - There are no fees applied to Fixed Funding campaigns that don't meet their goal - all backers are refunded within 5 business days from
>     the campaign's end date.
> - No fees are applied to contributions refunded through Indiegogo. The full amount is refunded to the backer.
> - Please note that your bank may charge additional fees such as currency conversion, wire fees, etc. Indiegogo always recommends you
>     contact your bank before entering your bank account information on
>     your campaign.
>
> **Raising Funds in USD with a US Bank Account**
>
> [image]
>
> **Raising Funds in USD without a US Bank Account**
>
> [image: IGG_stripefees-USDa.png]
>
> **Raising Funds in GBP**
>
> [image: IGG_stripefees-GBP.png]
>
> **Raising Funds in CAD**
>
> [image: IGG_stripefees-CAD.png]
>
> **Raising Funds in EUR**
>
> [image: IGG_stripefees-EUR.png]
>
> **Raising Funds in AUD**
>
> [image: IGG_stripefees-AUD.png]
>
> **Raising funds through an InDemand project**
>
> Platform fees in InDemand are 5% if you ran your campaign on
>   Indiegogo, 8% if you ran your campaign on another platform, and higher
>   than 8% if you ran on another platform and receive additional support
>   from our team (plus applicable Third Party Payment Processing Fees.) 
>   [Contact us](http://mailto:indemand@indiegogo.com) for more information.

See [this page](https://support.indiegogo.com/hc/en-us/articles/204456408-Fees-Pricing) for further information

Comment: I have edited this answer to provide an example on how answers should be on Stack Exchange. Provide the relevant content and provide the link for reference only. I suggest you take a [tour] before posting further. Thanks!

Comment: @pnuts I have updated the answer as the content had changed anyway. Please bear in mind when commenting that this answer was 2 years old, content, rules, opinions change. Also, if it really was an issue then you can always edit the answers yourself :-)